# BottomSheetDialogFragment intercepting the touches of other views behind bottom sheet

Tags: android, click, bottom-sheet

I have added BottomSheetDialogFragment in my AppCompatActivity, I am always showing this bottom sheet on my activity because I want to use it as a bottom drawer view. So everything is working properly as I intended.

Now the problem is I do have another view on my activity ( obviously ), and those view does not receive the click event upon clicking them,

I have tried disabling the click on the touch_outside and coordinator view of the BottomSheetDialogFragment, but it still is blocking my click event on other views.

I have put below code inside my **onViewCreated** method and on debugging these view i do get those views but still and listeners are nullified but still it is intercepting my touch events

```
val touchOutsideView: View? = dialog?.window?.decorView?.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.touch_outside)
val c: View? = dialog?.window?.decorView?.findViewById(com.google.android.material.R.id.coordinator)
c?.setOnClickListener(null)
c?.isClickable = false
touchOutsideView?.setOnClickListener(null)
touchOutsideView?.isClickable = false
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, I used a custom view and assigned `app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.bottomsheet.BottomSheetBehavior"`
to the desired view and wrapped it using coordinator view

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).